# Binance—Can't Withdraw Funds

Tags: iota-network, exchanges, binance

I bought some MiOTA on Binance. Apparently for the past month, many people have been experiencing the same problem of not being able to withdraw funds. *"Network Congestion, Withdrawal suspend"* is the exact message it says. I don't have that much in there but it would be nice if i could get it out. They claim it is a bug on your end that they are waiting for you to fix, others say that they don't have enough full nodes to support the transaction requests.

So which is it? And what do you suggest I do to get them out onto a new IOTA wallet on my computer?

Answer (score 1):

That's annoying but you have to wait for their withdrawal window to open. As far as I know it has NOTHING to do with a bug on IOTA's end. Network is doing just fine, people are able to withdraw from other exchanges.
Could you quote what they say about that issue being a bug?

Comment: Do you have any references for that information?